# Implement OAuth 1.0 API of tumblr React-native

Tags: react-native, tumblr, cryptojs

I'm trying to implement API of creating a post in Tumblr with OAuth 1.0 Authorization with form data using fetch request in react-native.

I tried `npm install oauth-1.0a --production` but I'm getting crypto error and application not start after installing this node.

I tried `npm install --save tumblr.js` using tumblr.js but getting the same error. for resolve error, I add below node but not getting expected result.

```
npm i --save react-native-crypto

npm i --save react-native-randombytes
react-native link react-native-randombytes

npm i --save-dev mvayngrib/rn-nodeify

./node_modules/.bin/rn-nodeify --hack --install
```

if anyone has an idea about how to implement OAuth 1.0 API in React-native please suggest what to do for this.

Thanks in advance.